# How to match HTML elements inside a here-doc in perl?

Tags: plugin-matchit, filetype-perl

I have a PHP file hello.php that contains the following code:

```
<?php

$heredoc = <<<HTML
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>I AM THE TABLE.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
HTML
```

I also have a Perl file hello.pl that contains the following text:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use warnings;

my $html =<<"HTML";
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>I AM THE TABLE.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
HTML

exit(0);
```

When I'm editing the PHP file in Vim, I can put my cursor over any of the HTML elements and hit the percentage (%) key in command mode and it will immediately go to the matching HTML tag. Unfortunately this does not happen in the Perl file. Typing the percentage key when the cursor is over an HTML tag in the hello.pl file does nothing.

How do I make this work in the Perl file?

FYI running the command `echo g:loaded_matchit` returns 1 for both files.

I have tested this in Vim 7.4 and gVim 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a full "how to include this in Perl," I can show you how it's done for PHP.

First, do `:edit $VIMRUNTIME/php.vim`. Notice that it runs the HTML plugins with

```
runtime! ftplugin/html.vim ftplugin/html_*.vim ftplugin/html/*.vim
```

Then notice that it maintains the `match_words` variable from those files:

```
let s:match_words = ""
…
if exists("b:match_words")
  let s:match_words = b:match_words
endif
```

Finally, notice that it sets `b:match_words` to a function that uses the correct `match_words`, either HTML or PHP, depending on syntax context (meaning it doesn't work if you don't use syntax highlighting, though it tries with some workarounds like `getline(".") =~ '.\=\%.c\&?>'`). It also uses `b:match_skip` to skip HTML or PHP when matching the opposite.

```
if exists("loaded_matchit") && exists("b:html_set_match_words")
  let b:match_ignorecase = 1
  let b:match_words = 'PhpMatchWords()'

  if !exists("*PhpMatchWords")
    function! PhpMatchWords()
      " The PHP syntax file uses the Delimiter syntax group for the phpRegion
      " matchgroups, without a "php" prefix, so use the stack to test for the
      " outer phpRegion group.  This also means the closing ?> tag which is
      " outside of the matched region just uses the Delimiter group for the
      " end match.
      let stack = synstack(line('.'), col('.'))
      let php_region = !empty(stack) && synIDattr(stack[0], "name") =~# '\<php'
      if php_region || getline(".") =~ '.\=\%.c\&?>'
    let b:match_skip = "PhpMatchSkip('html')"
    return '<?php\|<?=\=:?>,' ..
       \   '\<if\>:\<elseif\>:\<else\>:\<endif\>,' ..
       \   '\<switch\>:\<case\>:\<break\>:\<continue\>:\<endswitch\>,' ..
       \   '\<while\>.\{-})\s*\::\<break\>:\<continue\>:\<endwhile\>,' ..
       \   '\<do\>:\<break\>:\<continue\>:\<while\>,' ..
       \   '\<for\>:\<break\>:\<continue\>:\<endfor\>,' ..
       \   '\<foreach\>:\<break\>:\<continue\>:\<endforeach\>,' ..
       \   '\%(<<<\s*\)\@<=''\=\(\h\w*\)''\=:^\s*\1\>'

       " TODO: these probably aren't worth adding and really need syntax support
       "   '<\_s*script\_s*language\_s*=\_s*[''"]\=\_s*php\_s*[''"]\=\_s*>:<\_s*\_s*/\_s*script\_s*>,' ..
       "   '<%:%>,' ..
      else
    let b:match_skip = "PhpMatchSkip('php')"
    return s:match_words
      endif
    endfunction
  endif
  if !exists("*PhpMatchSkip")
    function! PhpMatchSkip(skip)
      let name = synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1), 'name')
      if a:skip == "html"
    " ?> in line comments will also be correctly matched as Delimiter
    return name =~? 'comment\|string' || name !~? 'php\|delimiter'
      else " php
    return name =~? 'comment\|string\|php'
      endif
    endfunction
  endif
  let b:undo_ftplugin ..= " | unlet! b:match_skip"
endif
```